# Why is my asp:Checkbox returning false when its checked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

In my asp:net app, I have 2 checkboxes set up the same way. One works fine:

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="uxOwnershipCheckBox" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="uxOwnershipCheckBox_CheckedChanged" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

**C#**

```
protected void uxOwnershipCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (uxOwnershipCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            DataTable ownershipDT = _dtMgr.GetTicketByStatus_Everyone(uxStatusDropdownList.SelectedValue);
            uxTktGridView.DataSource = ownershipDT;
            uxTktGridView.DataBind();
            uxTicketCounter.Text = ownershipDT.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            DataTable ownershipDT = _dtMgr.GetTicketByStatus(uxStatusDropdownList.SelectedValue, Session["UserNameSession"].ToString());
            uxTktGridView.DataSource = ownershipDT;
            uxTktGridView.DataBind();
            uxTicketCounter.Text = ownershipDT.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
```

The other one always shows `uxCloseDateCheckbox.Checked` value as false; even when its been checked. Therefore, the stuff in the conditional statement never gets fired! What am I doing incorrectly here?

**ASPX**

```
<asp:CheckBox runat="server" style="padding-right:1px; float:right; margin-right:170px;" ID="uxCloseDateCheckbox" Text="Closure Date" TextAlign="Right" OnCheckedChanged="uxCloseDateCheckbox_CheckedChanged" Checked="false" AutoPostBack="true"/>
```

**C#**

```
protected void uxCloseDateCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (uxOwnershipCheckBox.Checked)
        {
            DateTime dateTicketClosed = DateTime.ParseExact(uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your page load code as well

Comment: Also, Your uxCloseDateCheckbox if statement is looking at uxOwnershipCheckBox checkbox.  Is that on purpose?

Comment: Argghhh! That was the problem! Apologies for not catching that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though you're calling the wrong checkbox in the _CheckChanged method.

```
protected void uxCloseDateCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uxOwnershipCheckBox.Checked) //This is where your issue is..
    {
        DateTime dateTicketClosed = DateTime.ParseExact(uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Should be:

```
protected void uxCloseDateCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (uxCloseDateCheckbox.Checked)
    {
        DateTime dateTicketClosed = DateTime.ParseExact(uxDateTimeLocalTextbox.Text, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, sorry for wasting everyone's time with that. It works fine now. Cut & Paste does not always go as planned. :-(

Comment: Haha we've all been there.  It takes a second pair of eyes sometimes